# How to delete an Xml node in Haxe

Tags: xml, haxe, removechild

Does anyone know how to delete a node from an Xml structure in Haxe? I've tried the removeChild method, but so far, no luck: http://try.haxe.org/#92A8A

All I would like to do is remove the `<node1 />` from `<root><node1/></root>`.

This is what I've tried:

```haxe
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var xml:Xml = Xml.parse("<root><node1/></root>");
        var n:Xml;
        xml.removeChild(Xml.parse("<node1/>"));
        trace(xml.toString());
        for (x in xml.iterator())
        {
            trace(x.firstChild().toString());
            n = x.firstChild();
         }
        xml.removeChild(n);
        trace(xml.toString());
    }
}
```

I would expect to see `<root />` as the result, but it still outputs `<root><node1 /></root>`

Anyone? Bueller? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trying to remove the first child of `x` / the root node from `xml`, when you really need to remove it from `x`:

```haxe
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var xml:Xml = Xml.parse("<root><node1/></root>");
        for (x in xml)
            x.removeChild(x.firstChild());
        trace(xml.toString()); // <root/>
    }
}
```

Note that there's no need to call `iterator()` directly, that happens implicitly with `for (element in iterable)`.